ST-LINK/V2 connectivity issues on Raspberry Pi 4
I have next setup: Raspberry Pi 4 and STLINK/V2 debugger connected to it's USB port and PCBA with STM32 MCU I want to flash. I am trying to erase or flash MCU using st-flash and sometimes can do it successfully, but pretty often got one of these two errors:

"WARN usb.c: Could not find any ST-Link/V2 devices", but at the same time while running "lsusb" command I could see STLINK V2 device on the list. Replugging USB cable usually helps in this case
"WARN usb.c: stlink usb device found, but unable to claim (probably already in use?)". Same as in previous case I always could see ST-Link/V2 debugger in the list when run "lsusb" command. It's hard to say what helps in this case, but after few attempts erase or flash operation could be successfully performed, but I cannot see any specific reason for that.

I am pretty new to raspberry pi, python and linux, so I will be grateful for any help.
